# Poisson approximation to bound probability of balls in different bins

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose $n$ balls are thrown randomly and independently into $n$ bins. What is an upper bound that all balls land in different bins using Poisson approximation?

The exact probability is $n!/n^n$, since there are $n!$ ways of throwing balls so that they end up in different bins, and $n^n$ ways of throwing balls in total. But I don't understand how to use Poisson approximation to calculate an upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected number in Bin $i$ is $1$. If $n$ is large, the number in Bin $i$ has roughly Poisson distribution. So the probability of exactly $1$ ball in Bin $i$ is approximately $e^{-1}$. Assuming (wrongly) independence, the probability that all the bins have $1$ ball may be around $(e^{-1})^n$.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you calculate the mean of the Poisson distribution?

Comment: $n$ balls, $n$ bins, so the mean number per bin is $n/n$. There are more complicated ways. The probability any particular ball falls in Bin $i$ is $1/n$. Call a ball in that bin a success. The number of successes has binomial distribution, parameters $n$, $1/n$.

Comment: I misread and thought that $e^{-1}$ is the mean. Ok thanks :-)

Comment: Fancier still, let $X_i$ be the number in Bin $i$. Then $X_1+\cdots+X_n=n$. The result now follows from the linearity of expectation.

Comment: The mean of the Poisson $X$ is $1$. So $\Pr(X=1)=e^{-1}\frac{1^1}{1!}$.